# How do I specify a column on the foreign model in a where object using sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a join query in sequelize (SQL Server & SQLite), here is what I have so far:

```
db.Job.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'title',
        'id',
         [fn('SUM', literal('CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = "true" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', 'T')), 'True'],
         [fn('SUM', literal('CASE WHEN JobResponses.result = "false" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', 'F')), 'False'],
         [fn('SUM', literal('CASE WHEN JobResponses.result IS NULL OR JobResponses.result NOT IN ("true", "false") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', 'Incomplete')), 'Incomplete']
    ],
    include: [
        { model: db.JobResponse, as: 'JobResponses' },
    ],
    where: where,
    group: ['Job.id', 'Job.title'],
})
```

I want the aggregations to only be run on the jobresponses within a certain date range, so I am doing this to the where object:

```
where['JobResponses.createdAt'] = {
    $lt: end,
    $gt: start
}
```

However, that throws issue:

> Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Job.JobResponses.createdAt

How do I specify a column on the foreign model in a where object using sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify where for joined table you can do it in such way:

```
db.Job.findAll({
 include: [
     { 
       model: db.JobResponse,
       as: 'JobResponses',
       where:{
         $and:[{createdAt:{$lt:end}},{createdAt:{$gt:start}}]
       }
     }
  ]
})
```